# Angular - routerLinkActive and queryParams handling

Tags: angular, angular-router

### Update March 2021

Angular team finally merge the PR for that, you can looks at https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/40303 for more detail.

To use it, simply put

```
<div routerLinkActive="active-link" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="options">
</div>
```

Where `options` will have the either the shape of IsActiveMatchOptions

```
export declare interface IsActiveMatchOptions {
    fragment: 'exact' | 'ignored';
    matrixParams: 'exact' | 'subset' | 'ignored';
    paths: 'exact' | 'subset';
    queryParams: 'exact' | 'subset' | 'ignored';
}
```

or simply accept a boolean `exact`

```
{
   exact: boolean
}
```

### Original Question

I am using routerLink in Angular as below

```
<li routerLinkActive="active">
    <a [routerLink]="['/view', 10]"                 
       [queryParams]="{'offset': 0, 'numberOfItems': 100}" 
       queryParamsHandling="merge">
        <div>View</div>
        <div><span class="badge" [innerHtml]="viewCount"></span></div>
    </a>
</li>
```

So the .active class was added to li tag when the URL looks like

```
/view/10?offset=0&numberOfItems=100
```

If the URL was changed either `offset` or `numberOfItems` to a different value, the .active class will be removed, such as.

```
/view/10?offset=0&numberOfItems=120
```

I went through the [angular docs](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive) and managed to make it works by adding another routerLink but make it hidden as below.

```
<li routerLinkActive="active">
    <a [routerLink]="['/view', 10]"                 
       [queryParams]="{'offset': 0, 'numberOfItems': 100}" 
       queryParamsHandling="merge">
        <div>View</div>
        <div><span class="badge" [innerHtml]="viewCount"></span></div>
    </a>
    <a [routerLink]="['/view', 10]" style="display:none;">                
        <div><span class="badge" [innerHtml]="viewCount"></span></div>
    </a>
</li>
```

Seem the above approach is a little hack. Is there any configuration that I can set to make routerLinkActive works when router parameter presents with optional query parameter?

Comment: Just exploring the options here: Is that necessary to put in query params values (offset = 0, items = 100) in the `<a>` tag? If that is the default values, shouldn't they be set inside the destination component itself? In that case, you will only need one `<a>` here.

Comment: With my current architecture, It is necessary. Because I configure the 2 different route with the same component and resolve. One route needs these params and the other not. Then when resolve guard is calling, I will use the params to retrieve data accordingly.

Comment: I've just checked the source-code. It's comparing the exact URL so no, there's no configuration to opt-out the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same issue, but it looks this's by design according this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13205

vsavkin is a router creator.

Comment: Thanks man for the link. Our web app is still survived with the little hack I mentioned on the question itself. I might change it based on one of the answer on your link.

Comment: yeah, some guys provided workarounds but I switched back to optional router params

Answer (score 1):

You may find this helpful - extend RouterLinkActive - an item is 'selected' if it contains a string...

```
import { Directive, Input, OnChanges, ElementRef, Renderer2, ChangeDetectorRef, SimpleChanges, Injector, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router,RouterLinkActive, RouterLink, RouterLinkWithHref } from '@angular/router';


@Directive({
  selector: '[routerLinkActiveQS]',
  exportAs: 'routerLinkActiveQS'
})
export class RouterLinkQsactiveDirective extends RouterLinkActive implements OnChanges, AfterContentInit
 {

  @Input() 
  set routerLinkActiveQS(data: string[]|string) {
    (<any>this).routerLinkActive = data;
  }

  @Input() routerLinkActiveQSContains : string;

  constructor ( injector: Injector ) {
    super ( injector.get(Router),injector.get(ElementRef),injector.get(Renderer2),injector.get(ChangeDetectorRef));
    (<any>RouterLinkQsactiveDirective.prototype).isLinkActive = this.MyisLinkActive;
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    super.ngOnChanges(changes); 
  }

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    super.ngAfterContentInit();
  }

  private MyisLinkActive(router: Router): (link: (RouterLink|RouterLinkWithHref)) => boolean {
    const result = (link: RouterLink | RouterLinkWithHref) => {
      let resultInsde = router.isActive(link.urlTree, this.routerLinkActiveOptions.exact);
      resultInsde = resultInsde || router.url.includes ( this.routerLinkActiveQSContains );
      return resultInsde;
    }
    return result;
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi Doug, does this work for Angular 10? I tried this code in my app, but it doesn't work. Seems like the current RouterLinkActiveDirective does not contain a method called isLinkActive...

Comment: @MatterOfFact - I don't think so, when i upgraded to 9 i think it broke due to an incompatible injection/signature in the base class, I have dabbled with router overrides/extensions for years and found that whenever you do something too low level it usually breaks in the next release....

Answer (score 1):

The solution works with Angular 11. Sets the link as active regardless of different query params (only segments/path is compared).

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';

import {
  AfterContentInit,
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  Directive,
  ElementRef, Input,
  OnChanges,
  OnDestroy,
  Optional,
  Renderer2, SimpleChanges
} from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterLink, RouterLinkActive, RouterLinkWithHref } from '@angular/router';

@Directive({
  selector: '[rcRouterLinkActive]',
  exportAs: 'rcRouterLinkActive',
})
export class RcRouterLinkActiveDirective extends RouterLinkActive  implements OnChanges, OnDestroy, AfterContentInit {
  @Input()
  set rcRouterLinkActive(data: string[]|string) {
    const classes = Array.isArray(data) ? data : data.split(' ');
    (<any>this).classes = classes.filter(c => !!c);
  }

  constructor(
    router: Router,
    element: ElementRef,
    renderer: Renderer2,
    cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    @Optional() link?: RouterLink,
    @Optional() linkWithHref?: RouterLinkWithHref
  ) {
    super(router, element, renderer, cdr, link, linkWithHref);
    (<any>RcRouterLinkActiveDirective).prototype.isLinkActive = this.isRcLinkActive;
  }

  /**
   * this method sets the link as active regardless of query params
   * @param router
   * @private
   */
  private isRcLinkActive(router: Router): (link: (RouterLink|RouterLinkWithHref)) => boolean {
    return (link: RouterLink|RouterLinkWithHref) =>{
      const linkPath = '/' + link.urlTree.root.children.primary.segments.join('/');

      return router.isActive(link.urlTree, this.routerLinkActiveOptions.exact) ||
        _.startsWith(router.url, linkPath);
    }
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    super.ngOnChanges(changes);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    super.ngOnDestroy();
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    super.ngAfterContentInit();
  }
}
```

Usage (works as standard angular's routerLinkActive):

```
<a ... rcRouterLinkActive="active" ...>Link text</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tweaked the answers above for Angular 14.

```
import {
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  Input,
  Optional,
  Renderer2,
  SimpleChanges,
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  Router,
  RouterLink,
  RouterLinkActive,
  RouterLinkWithHref,
  UrlTree,
} from '@angular/router';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myRouterLinkActive]',
})
export class MyRouterLinkActiveDirective extends RouterLinkActive {
  @Input()
  set myRouterLinkActive(data: string[] | string) {
    const classes = Array.isArray(data) ? data : data.split(' ');
    (<any>this).classes = classes.filter((c) => !!c);
  }

  constructor(
    router: Router,
    element: ElementRef,
    renderer: Renderer2,
    cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    @Optional() link?: RouterLink,
    @Optional() linkWithHref?: RouterLinkWithHref
  ) {
    super(router, element, renderer, cdr, link, linkWithHref);
    (<any>MyRouterLinkActiveDirective).prototype.isLinkActive =
      this.IsLinkActive;
  }

  /**
   * this method sets the link as active regardless of query params
   * @param router
   * @private
   */
  private IsLinkActive(
    router: Router
  ): (link: RouterLink | RouterLinkWithHref) => boolean {
    return (link: RouterLink | RouterLinkWithHref) => {
      const urlTree = link.urlTree as UrlTree;
      const linkPath =
        '/' + urlTree.root.children['primary'].segments.join('/');

      return router.url.indexOf(linkPath) != -1;
    };
  }

  override ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    super.ngOnChanges(changes);
  }

  override ngOnDestroy() {
    super.ngOnDestroy();
  }

  override ngAfterContentInit() {
    super.ngAfterContentInit();
  }
}
```

The tweaks were adding the override keyword to the callback methods, casting the urlTree as a type of UrlTree, removing the isActive() since its deprecated and just checking for if the string has an index of the route value I'm trying to match.

Huge shoutout to the guys above though!