# Angular routerLinkActiveOptions

Tags: angular, angular-router, routerlinkactive

I have some link like this

```
<li routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-item">
<a [routerLink]="['contracts']" 
[queryParams]="{ activeOnly: false }" 
class="nav-link">Contracts</a>
</li>
```

You see here in params i have **?activeOnly=false** with this approach all is ok when my url is like

**contracts?activeOnly=false** 
active css class is added in html and user can see that it is active link

The problem I have that sometimes url can be changed like this 
**contracts?activeOnly=true&id=1** then **active** css does not apply anymore.

What i need is to have active css class on element even if url has changed with query params.

Example if url is like this **contracts?activeOnly=true&id=1**

**active** css class must also stay on **LI** html tag

Comment: where do you want active css to be applied `routerLinkActive="active"` makes sure that the link has css class active

Comment: Yes, it is applied when url have  ?activeOnly=false, but when i am on same route and just params changed, then it will lose css class?

Comment: do you have a minimal demo?

Comment: I can not add this to stackbiz, because this is issues with url active?

Comment: Here I created one for you. Can you now tell me whats the issue https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8f7jk8 . I tried with url https://angular-8f7jk8.stackblitz.io/2?activeOnly=false and it worked fine

Comment: No try direct link https://angular-8f7jk8.stackblitz.io/4?activeOnly=rr it will not work

Comment: do you want to completely ignore all query params?

Comment: Yes, thta is the point

Answer (score 6):

```
Path: '/' Component: HomeComponent
Path: '/server' Component: ServerComponent
Path: '/about' Component: AboutComponent
```

---

**HOME** SERVER ABOUT

Default home will be selected, now if you navigate to server

**HOME** **SERVER** ABOUT

Both HOME and SERVER will become active

### WHY?

Because in `localhost:4200/server` there is an empty path between `localhost:4200` and `server` and that is `/` that will keep home tab also active.

Therefore in order to deal with it you use `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact : true}"` with `home` tab. Now if you navigate to `server`, only server tab will be highlighted

Comment: I found that it worked when I used the new options:

        [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{
          matrixParams: 'exact',
          queryParams: 'exact',
          paths: 'exact',
          fragment: 'exact'
        }"

Answer (score 1):

RouterLinkActive if used with queryParams needs to be an exact match, So the above solution will not work. There was a proposal to make `routeLinkActiveOptions` but was dropped by Angular team.

You can define your own method to identify active.

Here in the below snippet I am defining a method is link active will return true if the path url minus any query params matches the routerlink path passed from template.

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router){

}

isLinkActive(link) {
  const url = this.router.url;
  return link.id === url.substring(1, url.indexOf('?'));
}
```

From the template assign `class="active"` if the method `isLinkActive` returns true

```
<li *ngFor="let link of links" [class.active]="isLinkActive(link)">
  <a [routerLink]="'/'+link.id" [queryParams]="{ activeOnly: false }">{{link.name}}</a>
</li>
```

Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8f7jk8

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming here as I did today, Angular (in March 2021) have resolved the issue of `routerLinkActive` for `queryParams`, more info can be found here...

[Angular - routerLinkActive and queryParams handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45450788/angular-routerlinkactive-and-queryparams-handling)

```
<div routerLinkActive="active-link" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="options">
</div>
```

Where `options` will have the either the shape of IsActiveMatchOptions

```
export declare interface IsActiveMatchOptions {
    fragment: 'exact' | 'ignored';
    matrixParams: 'exact' | 'subset' | 'ignored';
    paths: 'exact' | 'subset';
    queryParams: 'exact' | 'subset' | 'ignored';
}
```

or simply accept a boolean `exact`

```
{
   exact: boolean
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32344639)

Comment: Hey @ahuemmer, Good point, my response updated accordingly here